# PHP Array and Google Analytics V3 API

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, google-analytics-api

I am using the Google Analytics V3 PHP OAuht API. When using Simple.php in Google Analytics API Example the data are returned as PHP arrays. I am using the following call to get a more detailed answer to some specific data. It works fine.

```
$ids = "ga:xxxxxx";
$start_date = "2011-01-01";
$end_date = "2011-11-30";
$metrics = "ga:visits,ga:pageviews";
$dimensions = "ga:browser";
$optParams = array('dimensions' => $dimensions);
$data = $service->data_ga->get($ids,$start_date,$end_date,$metrics,$optParams);
```

Output of the Array is

```
       Data

Array
(
    [kind] => analytics#gaData
    [id] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxxxx&dimensions=ga:browser&metrics=ga:visits,ga:pageviews&start-date=2011-01-01&end-date=2011-11-30&start-index=1&max-results=1000
    [query] => Array
        (
            [start-date] => 2011-01-01
            [end-date] => 2011-11-30
            [ids] => ga:xxxxxxxx
            [dimensions] => ga:browser
            [metrics] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ga:visits
                    [1] => ga:pageviews
                )

            [start-index] => 1
            [max-results] => 1000
        )

    [itemsPerPage] => 1000
    [totalResults] => 220
    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxx&dimensions=ga:browser&metrics=ga:visits,ga:pageviews&start-date=2011-01-01&end-date=2011-11-30&start-index=1&max-results=1000
    [profileInfo] => Array
        (
            [profileId] => xxxxx
            [accountId] => xxxxx
            [webPropertyId] => UA-xxxxxx-x
            [internalWebPropertyId] => xxxxxxxxxx
            [profileName] => xxxxx.com
            [tableId] => ga:xxxxxxxx
        )

    [containsSampledData] => 
    [columnHeaders] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ga:browser
                    [columnType] => DIMENSION
                    [dataType] => STRING
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ga:visits
                    [columnType] => METRIC
                    [dataType] => INTEGER
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ga:pageviews
                    [columnType] => METRIC
                    [dataType] => INTEGER
                )

        )

    [totalsForAllResults] => Array
        (
            [ga:visits] => 36197
            [ga:pageviews] => 123000
        )

    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => (not set)
                    [1] => 459
                    [2] => 1237
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12345
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 440955
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Alexa Toolbar
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Android Browser
                    [1] => 4177
                    [2] => 9896
                )

    ....

    The [Rows] Array has 219 entries.
```

Now the problem. I have spent the last week trying to parse this into an HTML table or anything that looks presentable. I have come close, but it seems this multi-dimensional array is beyond what I am able to handle. I am also trying to keep the solution flexible enough to handle more metrics or dimensions if they are added as well. I am self-taught PHP, so maybe I am missing a function or two that could make this easier. Thanks again for any hints, tips of ideas to make this work.

---

I got a bit further, but I does not fully format the way I want...maybe someone can see where I went wrong

```
$output = $service->data_ga->get($ids,$start_date,$end_date,$metrics,$optParams);
echo'<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="1" cellpadding="2"
cellspacing="2">
<tbody><tr>';
foreach ($output['columnHeaders'] as $header) {
print "<td>";
printf('%25s', $header['name']);
print "</td>";
}
print "</tr>";
foreach ($output['rows'] as $row) {
print "<td>";
foreach ($row as $column)
printf('%25s', $column);
print "</td>";
}
print "\n";
echo'
</tbody>
</table>';
```

I still can't seem to get the rows to display right.

Comment: What's exactly your problem here?

Comment: I am trying to format the PHP Array into an HTML table. I can't seem to make heads or tails of the multi-dimensional array to output in a more user friendly way.

Comment: i am getting a 403 error. Can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755564/goole-analytics-api-error

Answer (score 2):

To get you on your way use

```
$data [rows][$i][$j][columnHeaders] [0][name]
$data [rows][$i][$j][columnHeaders] [1][name]
```

and for rows use something like

```
$data [rows][0][1]
```

You will have to get the variable via increment with something like:

```
var =(count($data [columnHeaders]));

   for ($i='0'; $i<=$var; $i++) {
    echo '.$data [columnHeaders] [$i][name].';}
```

This should get you on your way towards building your table. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in your `foreach` for the table body rows. You appear to have missed the rows out. Wrap it in another loop to print out `tr` around the set of `tds`.

This is what I used for printing out a table of analytics data:

```
$data = $analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profileId, $dateFrom, $dateTo, $metrics, array('dimensions' => $dimensions));

<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php 
                    foreach ($data->columnHeaders as $header) {
                        $headerName = ucwords(preg_replace('/(\w+)([A-Z])/U', '\\1 \\2', str_replace('ga:', '', $header->name)));
                        print '<th>';
                        printf('%s', $headerName);
                        print '</th>';
                    }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
            foreach ($data->rows as $row) {
                print '<tr>';
                foreach ($row as $cell) {
                    print '<td>';
                    printf('%s', $cell);
                    print '</td>';
                }
                print '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```