# Google API Query to get range of visits?

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api

I use the Yii framework with the JGoogleAPI extension as follows:

```
$service = Yii::app()->JGoogleAPI->getService('Analytics');
$optParams = array(
 'metrics' => 'ga:visits',
 'max-results' => '1'
);

$gaData = 
  $service->data_ga->get( 
    'ga:XXXXXXX',
    '2012-12-19',
    '2012-12-21',
    'ga:visits',
    $optParams
  );
```

If I had 10 hits on the 19th, 20 hits on the 20th, and 30 hits on the 21st, this query gives me: 30 + 20 + 10 = 60. However, I want ONE query that returns rows for each day.

Ie, not this:

```
array[0] = 60
```

But rather this:

```
array[0] = 10
array[1] = 20
array[2] = 30
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I think you will end up with a loop on the `data_ga->get`. But I did not research this (yet). Perhaps this can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295702/php-array-and-google-analytics-v3-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Accessing Google Analytics with Google Client API and PHP tutorial](http://enarion.net/programming/php/google-client-api/google-client-api-analytics-tutorial/)

Looks like you need to add some dimensions:

```
$dimensions = 'ga:date,ga:year,ga:month,ga:day';

$gaData = 
  $service->data_ga->get( 
    'ga:XXXXXXX',
    '2012-12-19',
    '2012-12-21',
    'ga:visits',
    array('dimensions' => $dimensions)
  );
```

And, if you run it in the [Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/), you'll see a result for each day.

[image]

Of course you could leave in just the date:

[image]

Not sure why the metric of `ga:visits` and `max-results` is set to one in your example and included in the `optParams`. There is already a place for metrics and you can include multiple metrics there if you want.